# REST request with oauth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I am missing something that should be very easy!

I am using oauth-plugin gem to access jira. I could easily build the consumer part, but now I don't know how to make a rest request.

It says in documentation:

[image]

The gem's author assumes that it is self-explanatory how to make a get/post-request. But I cannot figure it out.

I've tried to use Net::HTTP as follows:

```
uri = URI.parse('/oauth_consumers/jira/client/rest/api/2/project')
request = Net::HTTP.get(uri,{})
```

And I am getting `Connection refused - connect(2)` error.

I thought it could work, if I use current_user and his token (jira in my case):

```
current_user.jira.get('/oauth_consumers/jira/client/rest/api/2/project')
```

And RoR says that jira doesn't have such a method.

I've tried to search online, but there are very few projects that use oauth-plugin gem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right with `current_user.jira.get`.
Just add `client` after jira and change path a little bit:

```
current_user.jira.client.get('/rest/api/2/project')
```

JiraToken doesn't have `get` method, while AccessToken (`client`) does.